# Android databinding error

Tags: android, 2-way-object-databinding

I have two way databinding observable 
In last updated sdk i have an issue like this. Who ever encountered this?

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> android.databinding.tool.util.LoggedErrorException: Found data binding errors.
  ****/ data binding error ****msg:Cannot find the getter for attribute 'android:text' with value type java.lang.String on android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText.
  file:C:\Users\Tom\Desktop\projects\androidstudio\work_projects\projects\app\src\main\res\layout\medcard_edit.xml
  loc:83:20 - 95:53
  ****\ data binding error ****
  ****/ data binding error ****msg:Cannot find the getter for attribute 'android:text' with value type java.lang.String on android.widget.EditText.
  file:C:\Users\Tom\Desktop\projects\androidstudio\work_projects\novamed\novamed_android\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_address_picker.xml
  loc:42:12 - 48:36
  ****\ data binding error ****
  ****/ data binding error ****msg:Cannot find the getter for attribute 'android:text' with value type java.lang.String on android.widget.EditText.
  file:C:\Users\Tom\Desktop\projects\androidstudio\work_projects\novamed\novamed_android\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_payment_card_picker.xml
  loc:21:8 - 37:54
  ****\ data binding error ****
```

Comment: were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it was some sdk problem, it solved after updating next patch.

Comment: Hi, could you mark your answer as an answer to your question so that the question will be closed? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try deleting .gradle, .idea, gradle folder from your root android project, at least it works for me